# BigQuery Error: Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 6328502092800000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using simple select query with Standard SQL in BigQuery.

```
select expiration_date FROM cards
```

But, It returns an below error,

**Error: Cannot return an invalid timestamp value of 6328502092800000000 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid timestamp values is [0001-01-1 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999];**

Could anyone help me for the same?

Comment: What part is unclear? that value is out of the range (being 200675 years after epoch start) so is not representable as a four digit year date. We don't know who put it into your database.

Comment: Yes, Those data in our database. But, We don't need to change, If we will use Legacy SQL then it is working fine. 

How can we use standard query for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is that *Standard SQL* and *Legacy SQL* have different definitions for the `TIMESTAMP` data type. In fact, Standard SQL has a stricter range of valid `TIMESTAMP` values, being `253402300799999999` the maximum value and `-62135596800000000` the minimum (take into account that your value, `6328502092800000000` is higher than the maximum allowed).

For reference, here you have the `TIMESTAMP` definitions for both SQL languages:

- `TIMESTAMP` in BigQuery [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp-type)
- `TIMESTAMP` in BigQuery [Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#timestamp-type)

The migration guide from Legacy SQL to Standrad SQL offers a nice [guide on how to correct the `invalid timestamp value` errors](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#timestamp_differences) you are facing. The main two approaches suggested are the ones below, but please visit the documentation in order to obtain detailed information about each of them:

1. Use a UDF to filter invalid timestamps.
2. use `SAFE_CAST` with the timestamp column in order to return `NULL` values instead of an error.

Answer (score 2):

This means the `TIMESTAMP` stored in your BigQuery table has the numerical value 6328502092800000000.

This numerical value is *intended* to represent the number of micro-seconds since the start of the Unix epoch (1st Jan 1970, 00:00). If you do the calculation, this is a date over 200,000 years in the future; the error message is telling you that dates from the year 10,000 A.D. onwards are not considered valid.

Looking at your value, it seems likely to me that something has gone awry and you are actually representing *nanoseconds* since the start of some epoch - the unmodified value should not have been uploaded to BigQuery as a `TIMESTAMP`. This may be the fault of the client library which you are using to upload data to BigQuery, or of the code that passes data to it.

If we simply assume your value is 'nanoseconds since the start of the Unix epoch', we get a timestamp on 17th Jul 2170 - possibly what you wanted, if you were expecting dates in the future to be stored. Alternatively it may be that we have the wrong epoch (in other words, perhaps you are counting nanoseconds from a different starting point?). In that case you would need to determine the correct epoch (it depends where the data came from!).